# OpenCart Taxes apply to everything but product price

Tags: php, opencart

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohdXB.jpg **Album of my settings.**

I have tried everything for 5h before I dive in to altering the code to manually add tax I'll ask here if anyone has an idea.

- All my products have a tax class selected
- The tax is applied to shipping costs with no problem
- The tax is applied to Low Offer Fee with no problems

However tax just wont apply to the product price. If you look at the checkout page image I added you see the product without TAX applied to it and in DDV(TAX) Field only Tax for the 8Euro ( Low Offer Fee) is applied.

It does not calculate in the product price.

In 5th picture under Store Settings > Options I have: Display prices with tax selected and In the bottom two fields I have three options: --None--, Shipping Address, Payment Address I tried the combination of all 3 and yet nothing.

Comment: is this a problem with login such that it is showing tax wen you are login and adding a product or you are not login yet and its not showing the tax only

Comment: No the tax is simply never applied on checkout to the product price. I mean it's applied to shipping it's applied to Low Order Fee but products no. I can be logged in or out(guest) same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was not an settings/mod/plugin/extension error.

The way I tracked down the problem was I installed a fresh OpenCart 1.5.5.1 on my localhost and set it up according step by step then verified if tax works as intended and so it did you I went step by step to compare settings on local install and live install.

After that failed I realized it had to be an error with the code. I knew it was either going to be `/catalog` folder since here is where all the checkout related controllers are or `/system`.

I backed up both folders from live AND **DIABLED ALL MODS/PLUGINS/EXTENSIONS** and overridden them with folders from my local installation. `/catalog` gave no results so i restored the old one.

However upon overriding `/system` folder the tax started working again. Possibly it was a fault cron/backup job, someone toying with settings, plugins or code.